# Ansible - check variable type

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Apparently, according to several hours of searching nobody has encountered this use-case:

Its simple - I would like to execute some ansible logic depending on variable type. Basically equivalent of e.g. `instanceof(dict, var_name)` but in Ansible:

```
- name: test
  debug:
    msg: "{{ instanceof(var_name, dict) | ternary('is a dictionary', 'is something else') }}"
```

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: I know about the `mapping` filter that would resolve the use-case above, but it only works for what jinja2 considers a "mapping", which can be whatever (e.g. I have no idea what it is). I would like to know if there is a proper solution to this issue.

Comment: If you really think "mapping" is not "a proper solution" why don't you post an example to prove it?

Comment: The example is in the question title. I did not ask for a way to test whether something is whatever jinja2 developers think "mapping" is. I asked for a way to check variable type. This means ability check whether something is a list, a set, a dict and so on and differentiating between all of those. I used a dict here only as an example. In absence of other answers I have marked yours as one, since there's no other way to do it without a custom filter, but this is definitely not a real solution to the problem I described.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Ansible version 2.3 there is `type_debug`:

```
- name: test
  debug:
        msg: "{{ (( var_name | type_debug) == 'dict') | ternary('is a dictionary', 'is something else') }}"
```

Note that the docs state a preference for ['type tests'](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#type-tests).

Answer (score 14):

Q: ***"Execute some ansible logic depending on the variable type."***

A: [The tests](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-tests) including [*mapping*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-tests.mapping)
work as expected. For example, the tasks below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        myvar:
          key1: value1
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (myvar is mapping)|
                 ternary('is a dictionary', 'is something else') }}"
```

give

```yaml
    msg: is a dictionary
```

---

Q: ***"Ansible - check variable type"***

A: An option would be to [discover the data type](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#discovering-the-data-type) and dynamically *`include_tasks`*. For example, the tasks below

```yaml
shell> cat tasks-int
- debug:
    msg: Processing integer {{ item }}

shell> cat tasks-str
- debug:
    msg: Processing string {{ item }}

shell> cat tasks-list
- debug:
    msg: Processing list {{ item }}

shell> cat tasks-dict
- debug:
    msg: Processing dictionary {{ item }}
```

with this playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test:
    - 123
    - '123'
    - [a,b,c]
    - {key1: value1}
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: "tasks-{{ item|type_debug }}"
      loop: "{{ test }}"
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: Processing integer 123

  msg: Processing string 123

  msg: Processing list ['a', 'b', 'c']

  msg: 'Processing dictionary {''key1'': ''value1''}'
```

If you want to simulate the *switch* statement create a dictionary

```yaml
  case:
    int: tasks-int
    str: tasks-str
    list: tasks-list
    dict: tasks-dict
    default: tasks-default
```

and use it in the include

```yaml
    - include_tasks: "{{ case[item|type_debug]|d(case.default) }}"
      loop: "{{ test }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Older question, but you can do this easily with a Python [custom filter plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/filter.html#using-filter-plugins). Granted it would give you Python specific types, but that may be fine for your use case.

This could work. It just needs to be placed in a folder named `filter_plugins` alongside your playbook or role.

```py
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    raise Exception("Must be using Python 3")

def get_type(var, **kwargs):
    return type(var)

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            "get_type": get_type
        }
```

Then in your playbook:

```yaml
- name: test
  debug:
    msg: "{{ var_name | get_type }}"
```