# Ansible when all item in loop is true

Tags: ansible

Let say, I have this directory structure:

```
# ls /root/ansible_test/
one  two
```

And the playbooks looks like this:

```yaml
- name: gathering all dirs
  stat:
    path: /root/ansible_test/{{ item }}/
  register: dir_check
  changed_when: false
  check_mode: no
  loop:
    - "one"
    - "two"
    - "three"

- name: check all of the dirs are created
  set_fact:
    all_dirs_created: true
  when: item.stat.exists == true
  loop: "{{ dir_check.results }}"

- debug:
    msg: "Not all dirs are created!"
  when: all_dirs_created is not defined
```

My problem is that the "one" and "two" dirs are created, so the fact will be defined because if one dir exists, then the loop will return true. I also tried opposite and checked `item.stat.exists == false` but if one dir is not created (three) then fact will be created also.

I would like to play the task `set_fact` only if all of the item in the loop is true or if one of them is false. How do I achieve this in this case?

Comment: Parts of the answer can be found under [conditionals for skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71148510/6771046), would it answer your question?

Comment: What is the reason you want to do that? Ansible is made to describe a desired state, and thanks to [idempotency](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Idempotency), in Ansible one would just create the directories `one`, `two` and `three`, to be sure the desired state  is present, and Ansible will deal with not recreating them If they exists already.

Comment: @U880D I think not, or I can't see there is a part which answers my question at all

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Ofcourse, for creating dirs it will be easy, but in my case I should use it for another purpose. I just wanted to be simple as much as possible, not used my complicated code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: ***`set_fact` only if all of the items in the loop are true or if one of them is false***

A: Count the items. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dirs_missing: "{{ _all|int - _exist|int }}"
      vars:
        _all: "{{ dir_check.results|length }}"
        _exist: "{{ dir_check.results|
                    map(attribute='stat.exists')|
                    select|length }}"
```

gives (in your case)

```yaml
  dirs_missing: '1'
```

Now, you can set whatever you want, e.g.

```yaml
    - name: check all of the dirs are created
      set_fact:
        all_dirs_created: true
      when: dirs_missing|int == 0

    - debug:
        msg: "Not all dirs are created!
              (Exactly {{ dirs_missing }} missing.)"
      when: all_dirs_created is not defined
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [check all of the dirs are created] ********************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Not all dirs are created! (Exactly 1 missing.)
```

---

You can simplify the code by using the filter *counter* from the latest collection [Community.General](https://ansible.fontein.de/collections/community/general/index.html#community-general). See [Counting elements in a sequence](https://ansible.fontein.de/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_counting_elements_in_sequence.html#counting-elements-in-a-sequence), e.g.

```yaml
    - name: check all of the dirs are created
      set_fact:
        all_dirs_created: true
      when: _counts[false] is not defined
      vars:
        _counts: "{{ dir_check.results|
                     map(attribute='stat.exists')|
                     community.general.counter }}"
```

---

The solutions above counted the items of the list to enable the evaluation of the option *`if one of them is false`*. The code can be simplified further if the counting of the items is not necessary. For example, test if [*all*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-value-is-true) items are *true*

```yaml
    - name: check all of the dirs are created
      set_fact:
        all_dirs_created: true
      when: dir_check.results|map(attribute='stat.exists') is all
```

However, then you have to test the existence of the variable *all_dirs_created*. More practical is setting both values. Ultimately, the expected functionality of your last two tasks can be reduced to the code below

```yaml
    - name: check all of the dirs are created
      set_fact:
        all_dirs_created: "{{ dir_check.results|
                              map(attribute='stat.exists') is all }}"
    - debug:
        msg: Not all dirs are created!
      when: not all_dirs_created
```

Comment: I find this a really good example for how [to make use of one attribute from each item in a list of complex variables (Jinja2 `map` filter)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-uuids) and [loops and list comprehensions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html#loops-and-list-comprehensions), +1.

Comment: Made a bit easyer to not set another fact, insted changed the when condition to: `when: dir_check.results|length - dir_check.results|map(attribute='stat.exists')|select|length == 0` But ofcourse, you gave me the point how to do that, so +1 also.