# Testing a task result which uses a loop?

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml, redhat

So the first task is always skipped because RedHat 8 is detected which should trigger the fail module to run but this gets skipped also. Is works fine without the loop though.

```
- name: installing packages
  hosts: ansible2
  ignore_errors: true
  vars_files: varsfile
  tasks:
  - name: install software based on OS distro and version
    yum:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      state: latest
    loop: "{{ packages }}"
    when: >
       ( ansible_distribution == "RedHat" and ansible_distribution_major_version is version('12', '>=')  )
       or
       ( ansible_distribution == "CentOS" and ansible_distribution_major_version | int >= 8 )
    register: result
  - fail:
      msg: error {{ ansible_hostname }} does not meet minimum requirements
    when: result is skipped
```

Comment: Does [Registering variables from a looped task and conditionals for skipped tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71148510/6771046) with the second example answer your question?

Comment: result has a value skipped to true if all the loop have been skipped
    else the value is false (if at least one loop has been done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding

> So the first task is always skipped because RedHat 8 is detected which should trigger the fail module to run but this gets skipped also.

with a small test setup and a [`debug`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html) task for the [variable name to debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#parameter-var)

```yaml
---
- hosts: test.example.com
  become: false
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Install software based on OS distro and version
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_distribution }} {{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}"
    register: result
    when: ansible_distribution == "RedHat" and ansible_distribution_major_version is version('12', '>=')
    with_items: ['pkg1', 'pkg2']

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result

  - fail:
      msg: "Error: {{ ansible_hostname }} does not meet minimum requirements"
    when: result.results[0].skipped
```

resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************
ok: [test.example.com]

TASK [Show result] ************************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  result:
    changed: false
    msg: All items completed
    results:
    - ansible_loop_var: item
      changed: false
      item: pkg1
      skip_reason: Conditional result was False
      skipped: true
   ...

TASK [fail] *******************************************
fatal: [test.example.com]: FAILED! => changed=false
  msg: 'Error: test does not meet minimum requirements'
```

you can see that the loop will create a [list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#list-variables).

```yaml
  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result.results | type_debug
```

```
TASK [Show result] ****************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  result.results | type_debug: list
```

Therefore you need to set the [Conditional](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html) to `when: result.results[0].skipped`.

---

Regarding

> Is works fine without the loop though.

it is recommended to simplify your use case with the following approach

```yaml
  - name: Install software based on OS distro and version
    yum:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
      state: latest
```

according the `yum` module [Notes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#notes)

> When used with a `loop:` each package will be processed individually, it is much more efficient to pass the list directly to the `name` option.

and as it is faster and consumes less resources. Furthermore the result set and conditionals are less complex.

Comment: whoops  forgot the yum module doesn't need the loop. And thanks at least I understand both methods better now.