# How to run ansible task with_items only when items not empty

Tags: ansible

this is my ansible task

```yaml
- name: "Add sudoers users to wheel group"
  with_items: "{{ system_users }}"
  changed_when: no
  user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    password: "{{ item.password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    groups: wheel
    append: yes
    state: present
    create_home: yes
```

when run playbooks with vars

```yaml
system_users:
```

got error

```
fatal: [integration]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'None' has no attribute 'name'. 'None' has no attribute 'name'
```

when I change with_items to `with_items: "{{ system_users | default([]) }}"`

got error

```
fatal: [integration]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'name'. 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'name'
```

add `when: system_users | length > 0`

go error

```
fatal: [integration]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    The conditional check 'system_users | length > 0' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if system_users | length > 0 %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): object of type 'NoneType' has no len(). object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Use the filter `default([], true)`

```yaml
  with_items: "{{ system_users|default([], true) }}"
```

Note: Without the second parameter *true* the filter *default* won't be applied if the variable *system_users* is defined.

Details: The error is clear. You can't iterate *None*. Take a look at the type of the empty dictionary *system_users*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ system_users|type_debug }}"
      vars:
        system_users:
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: NoneType
```

The type is *None*. In this case, you want to [default](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.default) to an empty list and skip the task. Quoting:

> If you want to use default with variables that evaluate to false you have to set the second parameter to true

For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ system_users|d([], true) }}"
      vars:
        system_users:
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: []
```

This is what you want. The below task will be skipped

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.name }}"
      loop: "{{ system_users|d([], true) }}"
      vars:
        system_users:
```

but the same task will iterate the list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.name }}"
      loop: "{{ system_users|d([], true) }}"
      vars:
        system_users:
          - name: alice
          - name: bob
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => (item={'name': 'alice'}) => 
  msg: alice
ok: [test_01] => (item={'name': 'bob'}) => 
  msg: bob
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ system_users|type_debug }}
          {{ system_users|d([]) }}
          {{ system_users|d([], true) }}
      vars:
        system_users:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.name }}"
      loop: "{{ system_users|d([], true) }}"
      vars:
        system_users:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.name }}"
      loop: "{{ system_users|d([], true) }}"
      vars:
        system_users:
          - name: alice
          - name: bob
```

Answer (score 0):

Whereby I prefer [the already given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77541072/6771046) as accepted one because it initialize variables and creates clear defined and desired states, just for the record an other possible approach based on [Ansible - How to check variable type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73749342/6771046)

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    system_users:

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ system_users }}"
    when: (system_users | type_debug) == 'NoneType'

  - set_fact:
      system_users:
        - user1

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ system_users }}"
    when: (system_users | type_debug) == 'list'
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: null

TASK [set_fact] ******************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************
ok: [localhost] => (item=user1) =>
  msg: user1
```